Strange error `Invalid Conversation Message Definition, selected type not supported in bots.` when deploying chatbots
Invalid Conversation Message Definition, selected type not supported in bots.
We are trying to retrieve and deploy the same bot version and we receive this error.
We have no recent changes in the lines mentioned

we removed running as user, created Changeset, deployed via changeset, and then retrieved the metadata again and then we had no error.
Only identifiers have changed in the metadata.
No idea how this helped but it works this way
